# Let $T: P_2 \to P_3$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(p(x)) = xp(x)$. Which of the following are in Range(T)?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T: P_2 \to P_3$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(p(x)) = xp(x)$. Which of the following are in $\text{Range}(T)$?
>
> a) $x + x^2$
> b) $1 + x$
> c) $3 - x^2$

So

$T(ax^2 + bx + c) = x(ax^2 + bx + c) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx$
So $\text{Range}(T)$ is of the form that doesn't have a constant term.
Therefore, the only one that is in $\text{Range}(T)$ is a) $x + x^2$.

Is this correct? This was an even number question out of Anton and Rorres. I saw a similar question on here, but it was not exactly the same so just confirming.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help @CyclomaticField

Comment: Yep, its correct!!

Comment: Thanks @Aweygan for the editing. I will remember \text for $\text {next time}$

Comment: Thanks also @AdriánNaranjo

Comment: You're welcome.  It's also good practice to include the question in the body of your post.

Comment: You're welcome!!

Comment: Noted @Aweygan , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\text{Range}(T)$ is a set defined, for this linear transformation $T$ as

> $$\text{Range}(T) := \{q \in P_3 : q = T(p) \text{ for some }p\in P_2\}$$

Let $p(x) := 1 + x$, so $p \in P_2$ and $T(p) = xp(x) = x + x^2 = 0x^3+x^2+x \in P_3$. So we get that $q(x) := x+x^2$  is such that $$q \in \text{Range}(T)$$

This is just so that the question gets an answer. Your answer given in the question is correct. In your question you also proved that the other items are not in the range.

Comment: Does the question have to have an answer?

Comment: I think it has, because it stops the run for looking answers. This way the question is not anymore in the unanswered section. People usually looks that section seeking questions to answer it. When you get the answer by yourself or someone say's it in the comments usually 1)You could answer your own question and accept 2) The person with the comment should answer the question or 3)Someone answer the question given properly credit to the answer in comments.

Comment: See this meta  [What to do, if you figure out the answer to your own question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/what-to-do-if-you-figure-out-the-answer-to-your-own-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) and this one [What should one do when one's question has been answered in the comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments?noredirect=1&lq=1). In didn't set comunity wiki because in my view this ways is some approach at other angle and not exactly the same as pointed out by you or others in comment.